# Will codes be loaded on the RAM when I require a file?

Tags: php, performance, require

I have a code like this:

```
if ( <condition1> ) {
   require_once('../file.php');
   ...
} elseif ( <condition2> ) {
   require_once('../file.php');
   ...
} elseif ( <condition3> ) {
   require_once('../file.php');
   ...
} else {
   ...
}
```

Now I want to write it like this which is more readable:

```
require_once('../file.php');

if ( <condition1> ) {
   ...
} elseif ( <condition2> ) {
   ...
} elseif ( <condition3> ) {
   ...
} else {
   ...
}
```

In this case, `file.php` will always be imported, even when the `else` block is running and there is no need for it to be imported.

Is it a performance issue? When the `else` block is true, is there waste-processing?

Comment: Included file will be parsed. So it's better not to include file if you don't need it.

Comment: I don't think it has a big impact, depending on the file's size